# Como fechar o Drawer, após mudança de orientação?

Tags: java, android, drawer-layout

Como faço para que meu drawer se feche após uma mudança de orientação?
Exemplo: Em um primeiro momento eu abri o Drawer, logo após eu virei meu smartphone na horizontal, agora quero que esse Drawer que abril anteriormente se feche!

Answer (score 0):

O seguinte código fecha/abre o drawer:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
    } else {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT); 
    }  
})
```

Tu pode utilizar no evento que muda a orientação:

```
orientationListener = new OrientationEventListener(context, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI) {
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
            if(canShow(orientation)){
                show();
            } else if(canDismiss(orientation)){
                dismiss();
            }
        }
    };

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    orientationListener.enable();
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    orientationListener.disable();
}

private boolean isLandscape(int orientation){
        return orientation >= (90 - THRESHOLD) && orientation <= (90 + THRESHOLD);
    }

private boolean isPortrait(int orientation){
    return (orientation >= (360 - THRESHOLD) && orientation <= 360) || (orientation >= 0 && orientation <= THRESHOLD);
}

public boolean canShow(int orientation){
    return !visible && isLandscape(orientation);
}

public boolean canDismiss(int orientation){
    return visible && !dismissing && isPortrait(orientation);
}
```

Comment: editei a resposta